# How to get both values from a list box that is populating only one?

Tags: java, jquery, sql

I am working in an application where I have a  dropdown where all the names of  people are coming. Now I want that I will select one `name` and the corresponding `id` of that person will be selected. Can it be achieved?

my code:

```
String query = "select CU.name,CU.id from corporateuser CU where CU.enabled = 'true' and CU.isDeleted= 'false'  and name !='Universal Search' "; 


<select id="consultantListIntAva" name="consultantListIntAva">
    <option value="None">- Select Consultant -</option>
    <%
        while (rs.next()) {
            String consultantName = rs.getString("name");
    %>
    <option value="<%=consultantName%>"><%=consultantName%></option>
    <%
        }
    %>
</select>
```

Now I am populating all the names from the query but can I select the id corresponding to the Name?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate name with id?

Comment: You can extract it in the same way as you extracted name and store it in a variable.

Comment: @drgPP but in the list i have to show only name i have to show the id ,i m doing $('#consultantListIntAva').val(); using the name but how i can get the id

Comment: @drgPP can show show some code how to do that ??

Comment: where do you exactly want to show the id? in another field? and when? when the value from the select is selected you want to change value of this field by setting corresponding user id?

Comment: want to show it in an alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can do in this way. I have supposed your id is of type long:

```
<select id="consultantListIntAva" name="consultantListIntAva">
    <option value="None">- Select Consultant -</option>
    <%
        while (rs.next()) {
            String consultantName = rs.getString("name");
            Long id = rs.getLong("id");
    %>
    <option value='<%=consultantName%>,<%=id%>'><%=consultantName%></option>
    <%
        }
    %>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#consultantListIntAva").change(function(){
    var optionValue = $("#consultantListIntAva").val();
    var id = optionValue.substring(optionValue.indexOf(',')+1,optionValue.length);
    alert(id);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @lucifer edited my answer, remove the +","+ as it is evaluted as string, not as concatenation.